# Total up Subtotal in gridview

Tags: c#, oracle, gridview

I need to show the amount of Sub Total in my project but I do not know how to show it in the gridview and amount of Sub Total. Can someone help me please? I need to show it like this :

### Teacher Name    Class A     Class B     Class C

```
    Mia           23       32       24
                  35       35       20
                 ----------------------
Sub Total :       58       67       44
                 ----------------------
  Stephen         36       25       34     
                  22       31       19
                 ----------------------
Sub Total :       58       56       43
                 ----------------------
    Total :       116      123      87
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes you can achive this you need to follow the details given in this article : Group [Total, Grand Total in GridView](http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2011/02/group-total-grand-total-in-grid-view.html#)

After end you will get yoru grid like

[image]

Comment: wa.nice example. Thank you..ehhee

Comment: @20151012 - dont forget to upvote and mark anser as accpeted if you got the info you want ...