# How to add a row(dynamically) in gridview

Tags: c#, .net

good evening to all of you.I have a liitle problem.i have a gridview(id is gridview1) and bind that with array list objects.my gridview1 have a 15 columns.I want to add a dynamic row in my grid view because i want to show the total of amount column(this column in the gridview1) after change the ponumber column(this is  column in gridview1).

like this
   ponumber   amount
   1           23

### 1           25

### total          48

2            45

### 2            65

total          110

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you could do this. You could modify the datasource to do your sub grouping. You could insert some custom data on the OnDataBound event of your GridView.
Or you could use an ASP Repeater and write out your own table structure with 's and 's

Also, this guy asked a [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024761/total-up-subtotal-in-gridview), and got a good answer on building your own GridView dynamically